# Storing components in static classes viable?

Tags: c#, generics, static, entity-component-system

I´m struggling with a custom implementation of an ECS in C#.

I store my components in static classes like this:

```
internal static class ComponentStorage<T> where T : struct, IComponent
{
    private static readonly T[] components = new T[capacity];
    public static ref T Get(int index)
    {
        return ref components[index];
    }
    public static void Add(T component, int index)
    {
        components[index] = component;
    }
}
```

I do this for two main reasons:

- it allows me to store my components - as they are - in contigous struct arrays
- i can easily obtain the components without boxing/unboxing

I manage the components inside a manager class with tables etc.

My implementation is working fine so far but im nervous building upon this method.

- Is there any anything im missing like hidden boxing because of the generic statics? performance tests went as expected but i havent implemented any SystemManager kind of thing yet because its quite tricky to do so i dont want start with that if im wrong all along.

i couldnt find a proper answer for the static-generic-boxing question and i havent seen any ecs utilizing this yet.

Comment: I do this all the time without issue.  You shouldn't have any issues with boxing because the generic class is always treating the values at the specified type.

Comment: For the record, I'm not doing this within ECS, but I am using it in multiple C# applications.